# Error:Android Source Generator: [project] Package is not specified in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, xml, package

I am trying to generate a signed APK in Android Studio,

however I get this error :

Error:Android Source Generator: [project] Package is not specified in AndroidManifest.xml

There are some lines that seem to have a problem
however, I do not get it and how to fix them :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="2.0" package="project">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="20000" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="project.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature|signatureOrSystem" />
<uses-permission android:name="project.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" android:protectionLevel="UNKNOWN_DATA_0x0" android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS" />
<application android:theme="@style/Theme_Ab" android:label="Project" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
<receiver android:name="project.SimpleWakefulReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="project.SimpleWakefulService" />
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4242000" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyCpYsVH0zJSuL1SX5SuVoCP2RqeGqfSL1o" />
<meta-data android:name="bundleName" android:value="fr.project" />
<meta-data android:name="displayName" android:value="project display" />
<meta-data android:name="version" android:value="1.0" />
<meta-data android:name="build" android:value="1" />
<meta-data android:name="showroomName" android:value="project showroom name" />
<meta-data android:name="navBarCaption" android:value="navbar project name" />
<meta-data android:name="showroomAddr" android:value="address" />
<meta-data android:name="showroomPhone" android:value="phone number" />
<meta-data android:name="showroomMail" android:value="projectmail" />
<meta-data android:name="assistanceNatTel" android:value="phone" />
<meta-data android:name="savPhone" android:value="service phone" />
<meta-data android:name="savMail" android:value="service mail" />
<meta-data android:name="isRent" android:value="true" />
<meta-data android:name="mentionsAtelier" android:value="legal mentions" />
<meta-data android:name="facebookLink" android:value="facebookurl" />
<meta-data android:name="mentions" android:value="app mentions" />
<activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:label="name of app" android:name="project.SplashScreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:label="@string/title_activity_news" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about" android:name="project.News" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
<activity android:label="@string/title_activity_news_web" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about" android:name="project.NewsWeb" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
<activity android:label="@string/title_activity_news" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about" android:name="project.NewsPager" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
<activity android:label="@string/title_activity_cars" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about" android:name="project.Cars" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
<activity android:label="@string/title_activity_cars" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about" android:name="project.CarDetail" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" android:parentActivityName=".Cars" />
<activity android:name="project.Gallery" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
<activity android:label="@string/title_activity_staffs" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about" android:name="project.StaffGridPager" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
<activity android:label="@string/title_activity_cars" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about" android:name="project.Showrooms" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
```

```
</application>
     </manifest>
```

Comment: on the first line you have package="project", change that name for the subsequent folders names that you have between java folder and your own folders with java classes. Example "es.marcose.project" inside 'project' folder there should be the activities, utils java classes, etc.

Comment: @marcosE. so sorry to be so new at it, but I do not get it, as it's an app we're revamping from the apk we got in our Google Developper Console account, I do not see such classes in the structure